# Unexpected error on server associating the workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I cannot proceed with publishing the workflow whenever I add more steps. But if I create a new workflow and copy the steps there, it works. Does the 2010 workflow have limited number of If statements that it allows?

Answer (score 0):

Each workflow is associated with a XOML file, please check for the difference of XOML settings in New and associated workflow, you can check XOML file with the help of SharePoint Designer. You will certainly get some idea. As per my knowledge there is no such limitation, there might be some  custom Workflow activity which is not available after association.

Comment: how will i check this? @farshid

Comment: Just connect to SPDesigner, on the left bottom, you will see view all files, there under workflow folder, you will see all the workflows, select your workflow and download the XOML file for both the environments, use tool like WINDiff to check if there is any difference in both. Custom WF activity is deployed in Central admin, check for respective features.